# in what situation Do we this error message inc?

Tags: c

**panic 2017: Cannot recover from earlier errors, terminating.**

what does this mean in detail?
can anyone help me ?

Comment: In detail, it means that the compiler cannot recover from the earlier errors it reported, and thus is terminating.

Answer (score 5):

When you get errors during compiling, you should look only at the first one or two messages, the rest are nearly always follow-on problems due to the first.  Fix the first errors, and then try again.